# I want a function to be triggered inside another function with same input parameters taken from the above function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

The following function should take input parameter __RefrenceDistributerId which is passed in the next function

```
  function   loyalitypoints (uint256  __RefrenceDistributerId)  {

       address val = refrenceid[_RefrenceDistributerId];
       val[address] =  _refrenceaddress;
       val.transfer(0.001);
      } ;
```

In the MembershipPayment() i am passing the   `_RefrenceDistributerId` the same id i want to send to `loyalitypoints`function

```
    function  MembershipPayment(string _compneyname,uint256 _DistributerId,uint256 _RefrenceDistributerId,uint256 _AmountPaid,address _refrenceaa) public  payable  {

             require(msg.value > 0.01 ether);

loyalitypoints(RefrenceDistributerId)
```

I want the both functions to be excuted when user calls MembershipPayment method plese help me

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `;` in the last line of the first snippet.

In the second case, you are missing `_`. It should be:

`loyalitypoints(_RefrenceDistributerId)`

Use of the decimal in the `require()` is suspect. Consider `1000...` (wei) instead of `0.01 ether`.

Hope it helps.